# Swing - Multiple layouts architecture in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, gridview, layout

I'd like to achieve the following grid system for my Java application using the available layouts such as `GridBagLayout` :

[image: Layout]

I managed to create a similar layout but without the smaller buttons using only a `GridBagLayout` but when I try to add those smaller buttons, it's not working since it's not the same cell size.

I think that a solution could by to add multiple layouts to the **JFrame**, each one representing a section of the global layout, but I can't find the right layout to use.

Would it work to have one `GridBagLayout` that would be used to create all the bigger squared sections, and two large sections, one containing the item at the top left, and the second one containing the following 8 smaller buttons ?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on "how" you want the cells to resize.  The smaller 4x2 grid could be in it's own container, which would simplify the problem

Comment: Actually the whole JFrame cannot be resized, so I can have the 4x2 grid inside another container without problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I "think" you're talking about is using a compound layout, where you use one or more child containers to do specific layouts for particular areas and the combine those containers into a another container with another layout, maybe something like...

[image: Layout]

So the smaller `4x2` grid is actually another `JPanel` which takes care of the specifics of that area (and you could probably use a `GridLayout`) and then this is incorporated into a the larger layout

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 0.75;
            gbc.weighty = 0.16;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            add(makePanel(Color.DARK_GRAY), gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0.25;
            gbc.gridx = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            add(makePanel(Color.ORANGE), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            add(makePanel(Color.DARK_GRAY), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            gbc.weightx = 0.75;
            add(makeSmallerPane(), gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 0.25;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.weighty = 0.16;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            for (int y = 2; y < 7; y++) {
                gbc.gridx = y;
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    Color color = Color.GRAY;
                    if (x == 3) {
                        color = Color.DARK_GRAY;
                    }
                    add(makePanel(color), gbc);
                }
            }
        }

        protected Component makePanel(Color color) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(color);
            return panel;
        }

        protected Component makeSmallerPane() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.setOpaque(false);
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());;
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 0.25;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 4);

            int topGap = 0;
            int bottomGap = 4;
            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                gbc.gridy = y;
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    switch (x) {
                        case 0:
                            gbc.insets = new Insets(topGap, 0, bottomGap, 4);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            gbc.insets = new Insets(topGap, 4, bottomGap, 0);
                            break;
                        default:
                            gbc.insets = new Insets(topGap, 4, bottomGap, 4);
                            break;
                    }
                    panel.add(makePanel(Color.DARK_GRAY), gbc);
                }
                topGap = 4;
                bottomGap = 0;
            }

            return panel;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Great thank you, it's almost what I'm looking for :) The only issue I'm having and that I cannot fix after my tests is the fact that the Panel below the orange one, at the right of the 4x2 one, takes the height of the 4x2 panel. If possible, I'd like the 4x2 panel to take the height of this 1x1 panel, that should have the height of the other panels on the right of the window. I managed to get the right one to the good size, but the 4x2 panel stays the same and doesn't fit.

Comment: In my example, I gave equal height to all the rows of about 16% (I think it should have actually been 14%).  This is no guarantee as other facts like the minimum size of the components might play a role in the determination of the overall height supplied to the row.  Also, things like the `fill` property may also have an influence

Comment: Yeah indead, I noticed the 16% height (and changed it to 14 :P), but as you can see even on your own screenshot, this panel has a bigger height that the other ones below it. In my case I'm adding buttons inside the panels, and the difference is even bigger. Is their a way to avoid that ? It seems like the components have a default minimal padding or something like that :/

Comment: Not really.  The problem, as I can see it, comes down to a mixture of factors.  The preferred and minimum size of the panels and the insets.  I can get my example to expand the panels to the same size, by changing the size of the window, so that the insets/minimum size becomes less of an influence.  You might consider providing more of an accurate preferredSize for you other panels, which if they exceed the requirements of the small panel's minimum size, will prevent them be sized to small by default (until the available size decreases beyond the preferred sizes) - it's kind of black magic

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the buttons directly to the JFrame, put them in a JPanel that has its own GridBagLayout that has the cell size you desire. That way, you can add the JPanel and put the buttons of desired size inside.